# MessagingCenter and NavigationService using reflection

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation, messaging

I'm looking to improve my mobile application developed in Xamarin.Forms.

My functionality is as follows: onResume of the application I want to reload the page on which the user was.

Currently I use the MessagingCenter to operate with the code below.

Unfortunately my application is starting to have a lot of pages and it's not very readable anymore.

I am therefore looking to pass my type (viewModel) as a parameter of my navigation service - my research directs me towards the concept of reflection but I don't know if my problem is achievable.

```
// App.xaml.cs

            protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes

            Page currPage = ((NavigationPage)((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail).CurrentPage;

            MessagingCenter.Send<App, Page>(this, "Hi", currPage);
        }
```

Then in my BaseViewModel :

```
// BaseViewModel.cs

public ViewModelBase()
{
    DialogService = ViewModelLocator.Instance.Resolve<IDialogService>();
    NavigationService = ViewModelLocator.Instance.Resolve<INavigationService>();
    AuthenticationService = ViewModelLocator.Instance.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, Page>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
    {
        // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received

        Type viewModel = NavigationService.GetViewModelTypeForPage(arg.GetType());

        if(viewModel == typeof(AboutViewModel))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("AboutViewModel");
            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<AboutViewModel>();
            return;
        }

        if (viewModel == typeof(CardViewModel))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CardViewModel");
            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<CardViewModel>();
            return;                    
        }

        ...

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give you some ideas on how to make your code readable when using `MessagingCenter`.

**First**, you can have a BasePage which implemented the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` and a method which called `loadData`:

```
public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
            loadData();
        });
    }

    public virtual void loadData()
    {

    }
}
```

**Then**, when you create a new page which need to refresh when the application is resumed, you can make the page inherits from the `BasePage` type:

```
public partial class MainPage : BasePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loadData();
    }

    public override void loadData()
    {
        base.loadData();
        Console.WriteLine("loadData");
    }

}
```

And the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bases:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:bases="clr-namespace:App52"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App52.MainPage">

</bases:BasePage>
```

So you don't have to implement `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` in each Page, those can be managed in `BasePage`.

I'm not familiar with `reflection` so maybe can't help you on achieving that by `reflection`. Hope this helps.

Comment: My goal is to replace type comparisons and use a generic way for the generic type of NavigationService.